Azure Logic App: Gmail action with C# / Javascript code to read gmail email and make an external API call
I'm trying to read the email content on gmail trigger on Azure Logic app and using that trying to make an external API call.
Was thinking to push some parameters via email body/subject and then read that from the output parameters and then have another action method either c# script code or javascript code where I can write some code to make a call to the API.
There a few restrictions where I'm not able to send the data with the parameters apart from anything that the email. Hence I have chosen GMAIL trigger. Please let me know what would be the best way to read the gmail body and use that to make a call to the external API.
Please let me know what would be the best way to achieve this

Logic App is a no-code service. How can it have C# / JavaScript code?

@VladDX JavaScript https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code; C# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-run-custom-code-functions

Ok, good to know. What is the problem exactly? You are saying that you are "trying to read" and "trying to make an API call". What do you have so far? Where were you stuck exactly?


Please let me know what would be the best way to read the gmail body and use that to make a call to the external API.

To read gmail contents from Logic app you can use below design:

And then the Message Id will be something like below:
triggerBody()?['Id']


I do agree  with @10p, to use JavaScript you can use Inline script action as below:

To use inline script you need to have an integration account and need to enable it as below:

To call api, you can use HTTP action:

